# How to add parentheses/brackets to these two fromulas?

Tags: brackets

I can't understand how to add parentheses/brackets to these two formals, I've tried '/right)' and '\left(' but without success.
Please help, how should I edit this code to get the attached pictures (I've pointed out brackets that I need to add)?
I can't change the code so much. I need to save all the 'mathord' and 'vphantom'  and change the code minimally.

```
    \left( {{{\alpha_{{\dot{h}}} s + \alpha_{h} } 
\mathord{\left/ {\vphantom {{\alpha_{{\dot{h}}} s + \alpha_{h} } 
{s^{2} + \alpha_{{\dot{h}}} s + \alpha_{h} }}} \right. \kern-0pt} 
{s^{2} + \alpha_{{\dot{h}}} s + \alpha_{h} }}} \right).
```

and

```
    \mathop {\lim }\limits_{s \to 0} s\left( {{{s^{2} } 
\mathord{\left/ {\vphantom {{s^{2} } 
{s^{2} + \alpha_{{\dot{h}}} s + \alpha_{h} }}} \right. \kern-0pt} 
{s^{2} + \alpha_{{\dot{h}}} s + \alpha_{h} }}} \right)h_{i}^{c} = 0
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What about something like `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
(\alpha_{\dot{h}} s + \alpha_{h}) / (s^{2} + \alpha_{\dot{h}} s + \alpha_{h})
\]

\[
\lim_{s \to 0} s(s^{2}) / (s^{2} + \alpha_{\dot{h}} s + \alpha_{h} ) h_{i}^{c} = 0
\]
\end{document}`?

Comment: I should save all these 'mathord' and 'vphantom' because this is Proofreading. I can't change the code too much.

Comment: What is `\vphantom ` supposed to do here?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea, this was sent to me for Proofreading

Comment: Where did you learn `\mathop{\lim}`? Tell the person that suggested it, along with `\mathord`, that you're no longer friends.

Comment: Lol, this is not my code, it was sent to me from one of the largest publishing companies

Comment: @Tag I sympathize with you. But it's wrong code anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \bigl( \alpha_{\dot{h}} s + \alpha_{h} \bigr) /
  \bigl( s^{2} + \alpha_{\dot{h}} s + \alpha_{h} \bigr).
\]
\[
  \lim_{s \to 0} s
  \bigl( s^{2} \bigr) /
  \bigl( s^{2} + \alpha_{\dot{h}} s + \alpha_{h} \bigr)
  h_{i}^{c} = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### EDIT

Just insert `\big(` and `\big)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
    \left( {{{\alpha_{{\dot{h}}} s + \alpha_{h} } \big)
\mathord{\left/ {\vphantom {{\alpha_{{\dot{h}}} s + \alpha_{h} }
{s^{2} + \alpha_{{\dot{h}}} s + \alpha_{h} }}} \right. \kern-0pt} 
{\big( s^{2} + \alpha_{{\dot{h}}} s + \alpha_{h} }}} \right).
\]
\[
    \mathop {\lim }\limits_{s \to 0} s\left( {{{s^{2} \big) } 
\mathord{\left/ {\vphantom {{s^{2} } 
{s^{2} + \alpha_{{\dot{h}}} s + \alpha_{h} }}} \right. \kern-0pt} 
{\big( s^{2} + \alpha_{{\dot{h}}} s + \alpha_{h} }}} \right)h_{i}^{c} = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, but I can't change the code so much. I need to save all the 'mathord' and 'vphantom'  and change the code minimally.

Comment: I don't think these changes will cause extra unexpected effects beyond these two formulas

Comment: I can't change because this code is in Proofreading system

Comment: Then what can be changed and what can not? Please make it more clearly.

Comment: If that possible, could we save the code as it is and just add '/right)' and '\left('? I just don't understand where they should be placed. I tried some variants but it didn't work.

Comment: If you mean just add some code after and change the output of this piece of code before without changing any source code,  it is impossible, as I know.

Comment: No, I mean to modify this initial code by adding brackets with '/right)' and '\left('

Comment: I add the new answer.

Comment: Works like a charm, you're my savior. Could you explain why '\big(' works here, please?

Comment: `\big` is used only to specify a delimiter of a different size while `\left...\right` implicitly delimit a group, which is considered as a subformula. You can not let two group cross each other such as `([)]` (suppose they are two groups).